# ERwin Data Modeler Support

Tags: database-design, erwin

For the sake of not asking 5,000 questions here; are there any reliable sources of information about ERwin?

I have to use it for a course and I have been unable to find any website or documentation that is freely available.

Are there any documentation or resources available that cover basic usage of ERwin and how to apply everyday database admin concepts to it?

Comment: Is there a problem with the trial [here](https://erwin.com/products/data-modeler/)?

Answer (score 2):

The vendor does offer a [forum](https://communities.ca.com/web/ca-modeling-global-user-community/message-board/-/message_boards/view_message/2275086;jsessionid=B1DCAB224FBAF3418E6BC0DB5166730E.prodlr8?&#p_19) and a [knowledge base of sorts](https://support.ca.com/phpdocs/0/297/support/erwin_support.html) for the tool.  Plus, there is also the [manual.](https://support.ca.com/irj/portal/anonymous/DocumentationResults?productID=951&releaseID=ALL&languageID=ENU&actionID=2)  I don't really understand what you mean by 'everyday database admin concepts' with respect to a modelling tool, though.  Could you elaborate on that?

However, asking specific questions on data modelling tools is certainly on-topic for DBA.SE.  If you get to 'How do I do xxx in Erwin?' type of questions then it's fairly likely someone here is familiar with Erwin and can answer the questions.